# Unable to add custom navigation in other classes in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am new to flutter. I am creating UIs for both mobile and web view.

I followed a YouTube video and created a custom HeaderNavigation. It is working completely fine separately.

But when I try to add the header to another class I am getting a lot of errors. I searched google and tried to find different methods to add the navigation bar. But unable to find that.

Please help me to add header to another classes.

I am unable to add the code here, so I am sharing the GitHub repository link.

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/DeepikaSharma5/Flutter)

This is the error I am getting while running the above project.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nesting Scaffold(...) and placing the AppBar in a Column.

I moved the AppBar to the main Scaffold and placed the Cards in the body of the Scaffold - this seems to fix the issue, but I'm not sure this is the desired result. I've created a pull-request on your GitHub.

Try this, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As Stated in the Error itself, Expanded widget should be used directly under any flexible widget eg : Row, Column etc.

Whereas in you code in TopBarContent.dart at line 26, you are using Expanded widget under Padding widget

```
child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 20, top: 20, bottom: 20),
        child: Expanded(
          child: Row(
.
.
.
```

You should try removing Expanded there, if you want to assign full width there try to use SizeBox with width equals to `double.infinite`

Update:

I checked and found the your RCard is problematic here.

You should try giving the height to your column item like this

```
children: [SizedBox(height : 200, child: Headernavigation()),CardContent()],
```

Also,I see you are using Scaffold everywhere, dont do that, it should only be used for single complete screen everything else can be under normal widgets

Comment: I tried that. But still getting the same error

Comment: If you can, please run and check, there are some new errors too. Unable to add all of the errors here sir

Comment: updated answer with suggestion

Comment: Thankyou. Your answer partially solved my issue. The header width reduced when I add height.